# MomentJS add function not adding time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I've checked all the other forums asked on the forums here tried the clone method doesn't seem to work either. What I'm trying to do is make a key claim system and it'll get the current date and add whatever number the key has assigned to it for example key is assigned 10 days it'll add 10 days to the date. Yet it doesn't add time.

This is what it returns to console when trying to add 10 days

```
Thu Nov 10 2022 19:42:29 GMT-0500
```

Here's my code

```
let userDB = await userSchema.find({ UserID: id });
let keysDB = await keysSchema.find({ Key: key });

var todayTime = moment(new Date());
let todayCurTime = todayTime.clone();

userDB = new userSchema({
  Name: name,
  Discrim: discrim,
  UserID: id,
  Time: todayCurTime.add(keysDB.Time, 'days')
})

console.log(`Updated time ${todayCurTime.add(keysDB.Time, 'days')}`)
await userDB.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What shape does the data coming back from the keysDB have? Could you log out a row and edit it into your answer? There may be an issue with the data or the type.

Comment: Think I found my issue. So, my full function deletes key after it is claimed. I think it is deleting the key too fast to add the time from the key. Because it is returning undefined.

Edit: Deleting the key is not the issue. Still returns undefined.

Comment: This is what keysDB returns for that key but for some reason when I do keysDB.Time it returns undefined
`
{
  Key: '1561B-E1863-DAF25',
  Time: 10,
  CreatedByID: '1018369765766594600',
  __v: 0
}
`

Comment: `keysDB.Time` being undefined sounds like the root of this issue. Try using `findOne()` instead of `find()`, as the former returns a single document while the latter returns a cursor object that lets you iterate over a collection.

Comment: Fixed the issue thank you! didn't realize I was using find instead of findOne. My other functions use findOne don't know why I didn't realize

Answer (score 1):

`Moment.add()` *mutates the original moment* rather than returning an updated moment object [(source from docs)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/). It appears that it does return a moment, but specifically the value that the moment had before it was updated. This is a rather odd way to implement things, to say the least, so it's not surprising that it tripped you up.

You need to do your time manipulation before you read from the value. The following should work:

```js
let userDB = await userSchema.find({ UserID: id });
let keysDB = await keysSchema.find({ Key: key });

// You don't need to pass a Date() object if you just want the current date & time
const todayTime = moment();
const todayCurTime = todayTime.clone();
todayCurTime.add(keysDB.Time, 'days')

userDB = new userSchema({
  Name: name,
  Discrim: discrim,
  UserID: id,
  Time: todayCurTime
})

console.log(`Updated time ${todayCurTime}`)
await userDB.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Tried this also but doesn't seem to work either. I'll send my full function https://pastebin.com/raw/dHwSnm45